# Programmatic Gridview Understanding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This may be a fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

I've been working with a GridView control programmatically, loading it from a dataset in the code behind.  So it's a fairly simple process, instantiate a new Gridview, load the Dataset, bind the data, and then load the control.

However, I'm running into an issue where I can't load directly into the GridView from the code.  In the .aspx file I have a simple:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Supp_Data" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind my creation of the GridView is as follows:

```
Supp_Data = new GridView();
Supp_Data = OutsideClass.GetData(str_sql); 
//Add other features here (such as AllowSorting, GridLines, PageSize, etc.)

Supp_Data.DataBind();
```

And in my outside class:

```
public static GridView GetData(string str_sql)
{
    // string str_sql is simply the sql query that we will get the dataset with.         

    OdbcConnection dbc_conn = ODBC_Conn("");  //This simply instantiates the connection
    OdbcCommand dbc_cmd = null;
    OdbcDataAdapter dbc_adpt = null;
    DataSet dta_ds = new DataSet();
    GridView ret_val = new GridView();
    try
    {
        if (dbc_conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) { dbc_conn.Open(); }
        dbc_cmd = new OdbcCommand(str_sql, dbc_conn);
        dbc_adpt = new OdbcDataAdapter(dbc_cmd);
        dbc_adpt.Fill(dta_ds);
        ret_val.DataSource = dta_ds;
        ret_val.DataBind();
        dbc_conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        string tst_msg = e.Message;
    }
    return ret_val; 
}
```

But this doesn't display the grid at all.

Now, as a workaround (which displays the data), adding a PlaceHolder in the .aspx file and using PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Supp_Data) displays the data just fine.

So my actual question is, ***why doesn't the data get displayed in the GridView, but has no problem displaying in the PlaceHolder?***  Does it have something to do with the Page Life Cycle that I'm overlooking (I tried with both Page_Load and Page_Init with the same results)?  This would definitely help my overall understanding of this process.  I just don't understand why it would work near perfectly with one but not with the other.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Where / how are you binding the grid?  Do you check if you're not in a post back and call a method to bind the grid?  Key piece of information needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do a 'new' on the GridView, just populate it's DataSource and call DataBind. The object that the page was referencing is being overwritten in your function call so it has nothing to display.

Comment: Ahhh +1 missed that key point that is probably his issue, if its already in the markup it really is already `new'd` up.

Comment: D'oh. So simple.  I guess it's just one of those days.